# I need to read a csv with unknown number of columns and then write the data to a csv with a set number of columns

Tags: python, csv

So I have a file that looks like this:

```
name,number,email,job1,job2,job3,job4
```

I need to convert it to one that looks like this:

```
name,number,email,job1
name,number,email,job2
name,number,email,job3
name,number,email,job4
```

How would I do this in Python?

Comment: Check out pandas library. You can csv files using pandas. You can get the column names and then edit them as you want

Answer (score 0):

As said in a comment that you can use pandas to read, write and manipulate csv file.

Here is one example of how you can solve your problem with pandas in python

```
import pandas as pd


# df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")  # read csv file from disk

# comment out below line when open from disk
df = pd.DataFrame([['ss','0152','ss@','student','others']],columns=['name','number','email','job1','job2'])

print(df)
```

this line output is

```
  name number email     job1    job2
0   ss   0152   ss@  student  others
```

Now we need to know how many columns are there:

```
x = len(df.columns)
print(x)
```

it will store the number of column in x

```
5
```

Now let's create a empty `Dataframe` with `columns= [name,number,email,job]`

```
c = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','number','email','job'])
print(c)
```

output:

```
Columns: [name, number, email, job]
Index: []
```

Now we use loop from range 3 to end of the column and concat datafarme with our empty dataframe:

```
for i in range(3,x):
  df1 = df.iloc[:,0:3].copy() # we took first 3 column
  df2 = df.iloc[:,[i]].copy() # we took ith coulmn
  df1['job'] = df2; # added ith coulmn to the df1
  c = pd.concat([df1,c]); # concat df1 and c
print(c)
```

output:

```
  name number email      job
0   ss   0152   ss@   others
0   ss   0152   ss@  student
```

Dataframe c has your desired output. Now you can save it using

```
c.to_csv('ouput.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below:

```
with open('input.csv') as f_in:
  lines = [l.strip() for l in f_in.readlines()]
  with open('output.csv','w') as f_out:
    for idx,line in enumerate(lines):
      if idx > 0:
        fields = line.split(',')
        for idx in range(3,len(fields)):
          f_out.write(','.join(fields[:3]) + ',' + fields[idx] + '\n')
```

input.csv

```
header row
name,number,email,job1,job2,job3,job4
name1,number1,email1,job11,job21,job31,job41
```

output.csv

```
name,number,email,job1
name,number,email,job2
name,number,email,job3
name,number,email,job4
name1,number1,email1,job11
name1,number1,email1,job21
name1,number1,email1,job31
name1,number1,email1,job41
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! That works perfectly. How do I make it skip the header row? And how would I make it loop until it gets through all the rows (unknown quantity)?

Comment: Please share a real example of 'input.csv' so we can discuss it. (Just share few lines)

Comment: Code was modified

Comment: `forename,lastname,email,mobilenumber,jobtitle,jobtitle2,jobtitle3,jobtitle4,jobtitle5,jobtitle6 

bob,ainsworth,email@email.com,7891234567,Ashtanga,Yoga,Power Yoga,Rolling with My Yogis,S&M,Vinyasa Flow Yoga   

alice,frobisher,email2@email.com,7891234000,Aunt Liv,Barre45,Beats on Pointe,Callback,Dancehall,Floorwork`

Comment: @BenNewton check if the latest code works against your example

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this is the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','number','email','job1','job2','job3','job4'])
df = df.append({'name':'jon', 'number':123, 'email':'smth@smth.smth', 'job1':'a','job2':'b','job3':'c','job4':'d'},ignore_index=True)
```

We define a new dataframe:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name','number','email','job'])
```

Now, we loop over the old one to split it based on the jobs. I assume you have 4 jobs to split:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for job in range(1,5):
        job_col = "job" + str(job)
        new_df = new_df.append({'name':row['name'], 'number':row['number'], 'email':row['email'], 'job':row[job_col]}, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: thanks that's really useful. Sadly this needs to work for an unknown quantity of jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and Python's unpacking syntax to get the data from the input file and write it to the output file.

```py
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    # Skip header row, if necessary
    next(reader)
    # Use sequence unpacking to get the fixed variables and
    # and arbitrary number of "jobs".
    for name, number, email, *jobs in reader:
        for job in jobs:
            writer.writerow([name, number, email, job])
```